# making a todolist in Mootools

Tags: json, mootools

i'm making a todolist in mootools and having the following problem. i'm store my todo items in a cookie but the issue is i can't read how many cookies i've set so i can get the value of them.

my question is: is there any way to count how  many cookies i've so i can loop trough them and get the correct value.

when i put the getData in a console.log i'm getting my json but i also can't read the values from there. what am i doing wrong and wich other implementation do u advise me.

tnx in advance.

for now i've the following code.

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){



    $('add').addEvent('click', function(){

        var value = $('todo').value;
        var t = new Todo(value,"beschrijving",new Date(),1);
        var storeData = JSON.encode(t);

        var c = Cookie.write(value,storeData,{duration:1});

        var getData = Cookie.read(value);

        console.log(getData);
    });

});


var Todo = new Class(
    {
    initialize: function(title,description,date,isDone){
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.date = new Date();
        this.isDone = isDone;

    },

    getTitle:function()
    {       
        return this.title;  
    },

    getIsDone:function()
    {
        return this.isDone;
    },

    setIsDone:function(value)
    {
        this.isDone = value;
    },


});
```

Comment: look at todomvc.com for inspiration. or try mootools with model-based code that reacts to changes. http://dimitarchristoff.github.io/Epitome/ - see http://dimitarchristoff.github.io/Epitome/#examples/todomvc-reference for a working todo that's based upon this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be missing the core point of cookies - when you set a cookie with a specified name, it **overwrites** the previous value of that cookie. With your current approach, it will never contain more than a single item.

You have to keep an array of todo items and serialize and store that array instead of the Todo object itself.

Also, you'll grow out of max cookie size quickly this way. I'd recommend using HTML5 LocalStorage instead. A base wrapper of LocalStorage can be found in [Mootools Powertools](https://github.com/cpojer/mootilities/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: i thought about that issue by myself, now i have solved the issue indeed with localstorage.the only issue left is when i add a todo item and that works correct but i've to refresh the page to see the items. How can i solve that? I want to refresh the page when i add a item after click the submit button.

Comment: `window.location.reload();`